# Salesforce Sandbox refresh

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, sandbox-refresh

I have enabled Lightning functionality into eh sandbox with Lightning component But into the production we have classic version. Now if i refresh the sandbox then what happened ? Is there any kind of impact will happen with configuration part ? except Data into the sandbox.

Thanks,
Vivek

Answer (score 2):

Yes you will lost all existing configuration which you have done in sandbox and you will get a fresh copy of production without data (Unless you are refreshing full copy/ partial copy sandbox.)

This means you will also lost all your lightning components if they are not in production. So I suggest you to take a backup of your metadata and deploy it again after refresh.